# xcode 3.2.1 and ios sdk 4.0.2 download problem

Tags: download, ios4, verification

I have problem in downloading xcode 3.2.1 and ios sdk 4.0.2. The downloading completes successfully but after that verifacation starts automatically and verification failed. When I try show in finder it does not appear there.Please suggest me what should be the problem.

Thanx.

Comment: Probably some network hiccups that caused your file to be corrupted. Have you tried to download it again and see if it works this time?

Comment: First time there was another problem.. downloading continues beyond 2.49GB. I wait till 2.94GB and then abort. The second time I started download, above problem is occured. The size is so big that I have to wait for at least 6 hours to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried downloading again and finally i got it. May be this was network problem. 
Thanks "BoltClock's a unicorn".